# grant permission to facebook authorization dialog without browser

Tags: rest, facebook-graph-api

Is there any API based approach to grant permissions for 'client side login without javascript SDK'.
Here my application logs in the user and when dialog/oauth request is fired I want everything to be performed(application authorization and permission granting) through a C program.
Can I do it using some API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible.
Facebook using oAuth for authorization and permission granting, these steps needs to be performed at facebook servers only.

No third party application can accept user credentials and grant permission on his behalf.